# Solve $\log_9(x-4) - \log_9(x-8)= \frac{1}2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve $\log_9(x-4) - \log_9(x-8)= \frac{1}2$

$(x-4) - (x-8)= 9^\frac{1}2$

$(x-4) - (x-8)= 3$

The answer is 10 but I am not sure how that was obtained.

Comment: The manipulation in the first line is completely wrong.

Comment: Note that subtraction of logs corresponds to *division* of the log operands.  (That is, $\log a - \log b = \log (a/b)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\log_9(x-4)-\log_9(x-8)=\log_9(\frac{x-4}{x-8})=\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{x-4}{x-8}=9^{1/2}=3$

$x-4 = 3(x-8)=3x-24$

$x-4=3x-24$

$2x=20$

$x=10$